# Swift: using UIModalTransitionStyle.flipHorizontal shows a black view

Tags: ios, swift3, uimodaltransitionstyle, xcode9.4

I'm trying to implement `UIModalTransitionStyle.flipHorizontal` and it works but it shows just a black view. here is my code:

```
@IBAction func loadNextView(_ sender:UIButton){

    let nextVC = NextViewController()
    nextVC.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.flipHorizontal
    self.present(nextVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Any of you knows why it shows a black view? or how can show the correct view?

I'll really appreciate your help

Comment: NextViewController is in storyboard ??

Comment: Yes, the NextViewController is in the storyboard

Answer (score 1):

You need to load the VC like this [ **nextID** is it's id in storyboard ]

```
let nextVC  = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "nextID") as! NextViewController
```

Comment: This works. Thank you. Quick question if I want to dismiss the NextViewController with same UIModalTransitionStyle.flipHorizontal. How can do that?

Comment: You can use **self.dismiss(animated:true,completion:nil)**

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the presented view controller's modalPresentationStyle to overCurrentContext:

```
nextVC.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
```

Comment: What is the difference between `nextVC.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext` and  `nextVC.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.flipHorizontal` ?

Comment: These are two different things, please check Apple documentation.